Set up of virtual network integration with 2 app service plan within a single subnet
I am new to the networking aspect in Azure. I have a question around vnet integration.
I have 1 subnet 10.2.1.0/24
This subnet has 2 app service plan
App service plan A has 1 app service running
App service plan B has 4 app service running
Now I need to enable virtual network integration
Since all the 5 app service are in same subnet but in different app service plan so the question is
Do I need to create 1 virtual network integration subnet or 2 virtual network integration subnet ?
is it 1 virtual integration subnet per app service plan ?

You can attach both service plans to that single subnet.
The requirement for the subnet is that it must be no smaller than /26. Yours has a 24-bit subnet mask, so this is fine.
Each service plan requires 1 available IP address. In a /24 you have 250. The only thing you need to look out for is, if performing a scale-up operation, another available IP is consumed temporarily while the operation completes. I don't think you'll have any issues here.
